# Python Interpreter Version not showing in status bar of VS code on Mac

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

My python interpreter version does not show up at the bottom of the status bar on VS code on my Mac, it used to but suddenly stopped. Everything works but it just doesn’t show, I tried many possible solutions such as:

1. right clicking the bar to have the Python Extension checked (which I don’t even have an option to check)
2. uninstalling all the extensions then reinstalling it but it didn’t help. Even after restarting my computer.
3. I also can't seem to add python.pythonPath in my settings.json file if that has something to do with it and if it does how can I get that? When I try to add that in my VS code settings.json, it says 'unknown configuration"

Basically I would just like to see the python version on the status bar.

[status bar on vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z2yC.png)

Comment: Could you try to reinstall the VSCode?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Turned out it was placed to a new place in the status bar.
Here's how to pin it on the status bar now:

1. Hover over the `{}` next to the Python language chooser
2. Click the pin icon
3. The selection of the Python environment becomes pinned to the status bar on the right hand side

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that helped! Hey, how did you get Python 3.10 via miniconda? The latest I can install seems to be 3.9.7.

Comment: Ah, I typed "conda install python=3.10", and miniconda installed Python 3.10.0. Hmm.

Comment: The answer solved my problem. It has been quite annoying for a few weeks. Now it is solved.

Comment: @mph usually the latest version of most packages can be installed with the conda-forge source channel.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the current v1_64 Changelog https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64 and search for Status bar. It seems like it has been experimentally moved to the right beside the Language status and is obviously not that clear anymore as it is just a `{}` in my case. When hovering over it, it reveals the current selected interpreter.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The new python environment selection button had been moved to the **bottom-right** of the status bar, at first, I tried to disable and enable the Python extension several times and I cannot find the button at the original bottom-left of the status bar. Then I kept using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to search and manually select python interpreter before I noticed the new position of that button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. First, make sure that your load status is checked in vscode.
   from View> Appearance> Status Bar
   [Picture one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YuXQ.png)
2. Then go to the status bar and these two options should be checked like in the picture.
   [Picture Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSbMq.png)
3. Press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> like picture and Write `Python: Select Interpreter` then Hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   [Picture Three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gHOt.png)
4. Choose recommended or global interpreter.
   [Picture four](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSJoO.png)
5. If you don't see any interpreter version in the status bar like this picture, make sure you have at least one Python file open in vscode.
   [Picture five](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z207n.png)
6. Now when you open a Python file, you will see the version of the Python interpreter in the status bar.
   [Picture six](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXGGj.png)

I hope it works

Answer (score 0):

What everyone else says.  But I was debugging this in a mixed language project, and didn't happen to have python files open, where my shell was always getting the wrong .venv for some reason.  I figured out why, but just forcing the display is helpful - setting is Python.Interpreter Info Visibility

[image: setting of Python Interpreter info visibility]