# python.pythonPath saying "unknown configuration setting" on VS code on Macbook M1

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, pythonpath, pythoninterpreter

I have just started to get into programming and needed some help. My issue started when I would open up my VScode on my Mac and my python interpreter version would not show up in the status bar. I've asked a similar question:
[Python Interpreter Version not showing in status bar of VS code on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71119083/python-interpreter-version-not-showing-in-status-bar-of-vs-code-on-mac)

I looked more into it (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veJvQ88ULOM&t=193s) and found that I maybe needed to give it a path so I was looking how to set that by going to code/preference/settings/ then clicking the Open settings JSON (top right icon) to put python.pythonPath: "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9" in the curly braces to make it work but my VS code won't even recognize python.pythonPath.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`python.pythonPath` [has been deprecated](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11015).
`python.defaultInterpreterPath` is what you want to set.
See VS Code's [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) on using python environments for details.